# Howto replace a file in several sub-folders

Tags: linux

I've a series of directories containing a set of files. There is a new copy of this file which I would like to replace all instances with. How can do this with find command?

Latest file is in `/var/www/html` is called `update_user.php`

There are 125 directories with several other files including a copy of `update_user.php`. I want to replace these with the one in `update_user.php` excluding itself.

Comment: You have directories, not folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
find /path/to/old/files -type f -name update_user.php -exec cp /path/to/new/update_user.php {} \;
```

You should check if the new file is not inside `/path/to/old` and if so than first copy it outside and use that copy but.. it'll not harm if you don't - one `cp` will fail with `are the same file` error.

You can use

1. `cp -v` to see what it does
2. `cp -u` to update only when source file is newer
3. `echo cp` to perform dry run

I would suggest to check first if all dest. files are the same with:

```
find /path/to/old/files -type f -name update_user.php -exec md5sum {} \;|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq
```